# In SQL, how do get counts for multiple is_contains() statements in the same column?

Tags: sql, count, case, contains

I have a dataset where it shows each row as a task someone is working on. Each row has a task ID and shows the owner for that task, but there can be multiple owners. If there are multiple, they are separated by commas.

```
| task_id | owner            |
|---------|------------------|
| ID 1    | Owner A, Owner B |
| ID 2    | Owner A          |
| ID 3    | Owner B, Owner C |
| ID 4    | Owner A, Owner C |
| ID 5    | Owner B          |
```

I want to create a table that adds up how many tasks each person has assigned to them, regardless of whether that person is sharing it with another person, like below.

```
| task_count | owner   |
|------------|---------|
| 3          | Owner A |
| 3          | Owner B |
| 2          | Owner C |
```

I tried to do this with an aggregate statement using a CASE statement and is_contains().

```
SELECT
        CASE
             WHEN is_contains(owner, 'Owner A')  = 1 THEN 'Owner A'
             WHEN is_contains(owner, 'Owner B')  = 1 THEN 'Owner B'
             WHEN is_contains(owner, 'Owner C')  = 1 THEN 'Owner C'
         END AS "owner",
     COUNT("task_id")
FROM  tasks
GROUP BY owner
```

But the numbers that came in were too low because it would first search for Owner A, and if it found it then it would just count that row as Owner A and Owner B would lose one count. I need to find a way to give accurate numbers showing every time each owner was in the owner column.

I may be able to do this by using separate count columns instead of one case statement, but then I would need to pivot all the columns into one. Possibly I could use a bunch of union statements as well, but there must be a better way. Any ideas?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Who created that database? It is not normalized and should be changed. Don't have multiple values in a string. This is not how to create a relational database. Have a table of tasks, a table of owners, and a table of task owners to represent the m:n relation.

Comment: . [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL Server, you can use `string_split()`

```
select trim(s.value), count(*)
from tasks t cross apply
     string_split(t.owner, ',') s
group by trim(s.value);
```